# Anko DSL: right place for layout params

Tags: android, android-layout, anko

I am playing with Anko in Android Studio, unfortunately Anko DSL plugin does not work there so I am coding the interface manually.

Are there any clear explanations which layout parameters may I place in the each of 5 places? Some parameters work in the single place, some everywhere (height and width). What was the idea to define these places?

```
someViewOrLayout {

    _place1

    lparams(_place2) {
        _place3
    }

}.lparams(place4) {
    _place5
}
```